# Check how many elements of an array exists as keys in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object

```
const Obj = {
2016-07-04: 264464,
2016-07-05: 266458,
2016-07-07: 272720,
2016-07-08: 274352,
2016-07-11: 290110,
2016-07-12: 283604,
2016-07-14: 290356,
2016-07-19: 298452,
2016-07-22: 301793,
2016-07-24: 308439,
2016-07-25: 311762,
2016-07-27: 315518,
2016-07-28: 317712,
2016-07-29: 322961,
2016-07-30: 312415,
2016-07-31: 322962,
2016-08-02: 328265,
2016-08-06: 322963,
2016-08-08: 341632,
2016-08-15: 354271,
2016-08-16: 358108,
2016-08-26: 380486,
2016-08-27: 380495,
2016-08-28: 385578,
2016-08-29: 388026,
2016-08-30: 391542,
2016-09-03: 385575,
2016-09-04: 417260,
2016-09-05: 413816,
2016-09-06: 417249,
2016-09-07: 417244,
2016-09-08: 420326,
2016-09-17: 403546,
}
```

and I have an array

```
const daysToCheck = [
  "2016-09-01",
  "2016-09-02",
  "2016-09-03",
  "2016-09-04",
  "2016-09-05",
  "2016-09-06",
  "2016-09-07",
  "2016-09-08",
];
```

I want to find out if each of the items in the array exists in the keys of the object and how many of the items of the array are found in the keys of the object.

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the intersection of two arrays using `.filter` method. Easier way of doing than what was proposed above.

```js
let arr = Object.keys(Obj).filter( value => daysToCheck.includes(value));
```

`Object.keys(Obj)` extracts the keys of the `Obj` object, and the `.filter` return an array with `value`s that are both in `daysToCheck` and `Obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce function on array and for each iteration, check if Obj has the value for the current array element. If it has then increment the accumulator value by one.

```js
const Obj = {
  "2016-07-04": 264464,
  "2016-07-05": 266458,
  "2016-07-07": 272720,
  "2016-07-08": 274352,
  "2016-07-11": 290110,
  "2016-07-12": 283604,
  "2016-07-14": 290356,
  "2016-07-19": 298452,
  "2016-07-22": 301793,
  "2016-07-24": 308439,
  "2016-07-25": 311762,
  "2016-07-27": 315518,
  "2016-07-28": 317712,
  "2016-07-29": 322961,
  "2016-07-30": 312415,
  "2016-07-31": 322962,
  "2016-08-02": 328265,
  "2016-08-06": 322963,
  "2016-08-08": 341632,
  "2016-08-15": 354271,
  "2016-08-16": 358108,
  "2016-08-26": 380486,
  "2016-08-27": 380495,
  "2016-08-28": 385578,
  "2016-08-29": 388026,
  "2016-08-30": 391542,
  "2016-09-03": 385575,
  "2016-09-04": 417260,
  "2016-09-05": 413816,
  "2016-09-06": 417249,
  "2016-09-07": 417244,
  "2016-09-08": 420326,
  "2016-09-17": 403546,
}
  
const daysToCheck = [
  "2016-09-01",
  "2016-09-02",
  "2016-09-03",
  "2016-09-04",
  "2016-09-05",
  "2016-09-06",
  "2016-09-07",
  "2016-09-08",
];

const keysInArray = daysToCheck.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (Obj[cur]) {
    acc++;
  }

  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(keysInArray);
```